# how Create a graph comparing two dimensions

Tags: excel, graph, powerbi, comparison

[image]

Hello I'm trying to figure out how I can do something like this with that table

[image]

Can you help me? because when I use candidate A as a row I can't compare them in a single graph

Comment: use countif() to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with propoer structured data you can report on. This menas you need a table with column "Candidate" and a column "Opinion". If your source is not like this we can unpivot the data.

Go to m-guery by clicking on "Transform data". In m-query, select both columns, click the "Transform" tab and click "Unpivot Columns". Result should be as below.

[image]

Close m-query "Apply & Close". In power by click on the **matrix** visual, add the columns to the fields as shown below. Pay attention to teh Values because you need to set it to count in the drop down.

Enjoy!
[image]